# CXF server with Weblogic 10.3.3 - Apache ActiveMQ Exception

Tags: web-services, apache, weblogic, cxf, activemq-classic

I am using Eclipse Indigo with Oepe and I made a CXF server.
The configuration is correct: It's an EAR with a WAR, the WAR contains the CXF 2.5.5 library and provides some webservices. I have followed the cxf guidelines to configure for weblogic and this is my application-weblogic.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.1/weblogic-application.xsd">
<!--weblogic-version:10.3.3-->
<wls:application-param>
    <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
    <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
</wls:application-param>
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.apache.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.joda.time.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>javax.jws.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

I know that the configuration is correct because it works on my weblogic 10.3.3 server; however, on other weblogic 10.3.3 servers sometimes I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:506)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1466)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: weblogic.application.WrappedDeploymentException: org.apache.activemq.advisory.ConsumerListener
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:280)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:37)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:328)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:285)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:37)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:328)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:285)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:37)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:85)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1359)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:440)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:484)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:381)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:507)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:149)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:1221)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:367)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:58)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:207)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

As the exception shows, there is a problem with the **org.apache.activemq.advisory.ConsumerListener** class; what I don't understand is that I don't use apache activemq at all, is it something needed by cfx? And why would it work on some weblogic installations and not on others? I also need to fix it to work on any weblogic installation.

I didn't have enough time to see all the differences between the installations, as the weblogic that I have installed had no problem and weblogic installed by others had this problem, but I can tell that the working weblogic is a development mode on windows, and the others are either development or production mode but on centos linux.

I don't think the problem is on the application-weblogic.xml at all because I have tried a lot of options with no success, but I hope someone had this problem already and knows how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In OTN I saw this thread, that could help you in this problem:
https://forums.oracle.com/message/4302193#4302193

So maybe the named package is in your classpath in two locations?